# POI - Excel Separate column for different Id

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am trying to fetch data from mysql and write it into excel with some condition like below,

```
  List<DataClass> getdata = reports.getReportData(); //This will return data from jdbcTemplate
```

getdata contains data like below,

```
    deviceId    value  date
    T01         59        2-sep
    T01         67        3-sep
    T01         78        4-sep
    T01         79        5-sep
    T02         68        2-sep
    T02         69        3-sep
    T02         75        4-sep
    T03         70        2-sep
    T03         78        3-sep
    T03         80        4-sep
    T03         89        5-sep

class DataPosition {
    public Integer colNum;
    public Integer rowNum;

    public DataPosition(Integer colNum,Integer rowNum) {
        this.colNum = colNum;
        this.rowNum = rowNum;
    }
}

Map<String, DataPosition> excelIds = new HashMap<>();
DataPosition position;
// Start at -2 so when it comes to the first value, you add 2 to place the column number to 0
Integer currentColNum = -2;
Integer currentRowNum;
HSSFRow row;
for (DataClass e: getdata) {  
    position = excelIds.get(e.getDeviceId());
    if (position != null) {
        // Add a new row
        position.rowNum++;
        currentRowNum = position.rowNum;
    } else {
        // Add a new column (increments by two because you need two columns for the representation)
        currentColNum += 2;
        currentRowNum = 0;
        excelIds.put(e.getDeviceId(), new DataPosition(currentColNum, currentRowNum));
    }

    row = sheet.getRow(currentRowNum);
    if (row == null) {
        row = sheet.createRow(currentRowNum);
    }

    row.createCell(currentColNum).setCellValue(e.getValue());
    row.createCell(currentColNum + 1).setCellValue(e.getDate());
}
```

But It writing like below,

[image]

But I wanted to display like below,

[image]

How to print the deviceId and Date as heading for each devices here?

Updated code,

```
Map<String, DataPosition> excelIds = new HashMap<>();
DataPosition position;
// Start at -2 so when it comes to the first value, you add 2 to place the column number to 0
Integer currentColNum = -2;
Integer currentRowNum;
HSSFRow row;
for (DataClass e: getdata) {  
    position = excelIds.get(e.getDeviceId());
    if (position != null) {
        // Add a new row
        position.rowNum++;
        currentRowNum = position.rowNum;
    } else {
        // Add a new column (increments by two because you need two columns for the representation)
        currentColNum += 2;
        currentRowNum = 0;
        excelIds.put(e.getDeviceId(), new DataPosition(currentColNum, currentRowNum));
newValueFlag = true;
    }
    row = sheet.getRow(currentRowNum);
    if (row == null) {
        row = sheet.createRow(currentRowNum);
    }
if (newValueFlag) {
     Cell newCell = row.createCell(currentColNum);
     newCell.setCellValue(e.getDeviceId());
     newCell.setCellStyle(style);
     Cell newCell2 = row.createCell(currentColNum + 1);
     newCell2.setCellValue("Date");
     newCell2.setCellStyle(style);
     row = sheet.createRow(currentRowNum + 1);
    row.createCell(currentColNum).setCellValue(e.getValue());
    row.createCell(currentColNum + 1).setCellValue(e.getDate);
    newValueFlag = false;
    excelIds.put(e.getDeviceId(), new 
    DataPosition(currentColNum, currentRowNum + 1));
}
else{

    row.createCell(currentColNum).setCellValue(e.getValue());
    row.createCell(currentColNum + 1).setCellValue(e.getDate());
}
}
```

If i try with above changes then I am missing first row of each deviceId's value.

Answer (score 1):

Before creating a row , increment currentRowNum by 1 and add details in it. Then create static row by

```
Row heading= sheet.createRow(0);
```

And set deviceIds and Date in it.

You need a single row at the top so after the loop, you will get the complete map of positions and device ids and then you can create static row at the top that is at 0th position and add these device ids from that map using loop.

Comment: Can you explain detaily?

Comment: I am quite confused, It will be good if you update my code by your change

Comment: Are you getting proper output?

Comment: yes but missing first row values for all deviceIds like 59,2-Sep, 68,2-Sep except last deviceId values

Comment: It is because you have not incremented the row.Create a static row as heading before starting the loop.